# navigational controller not passing data from tableview to viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, ios6, uinavigationcontroller

The code for Tableview :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    ViewControllerDisplayMsg *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController3"];


    cellvalue=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detail.DisplayMsgString = cellvalue;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];

    }
```

Code in viewController3 :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.DisplayMsgLabel.text= self.DisplayMsgString;

}
```

The code above is not passing data its blank when the viewcontroller3 is opened.Why is the data not passing .What code is missing ?

Please help me out.Really appreciate the help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you created property of DisplayMsgString in ViewControllerDisplayMsg and synthesize it properlly ?

Comment: Hello Sir.   **@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *DisplayMsg;**


**@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *DisplayMsgString;**   This is how it looks in .h and I havent synthesized as it autoSythesized RIght in ios6.1 xcode 4.6 ?

Comment: no its ok you dont have to do synthesis in ios 6.1

Comment: Check UILabel connection in IB; Code looks OK to me.

Comment: Hello Matt I did that twice.

Comment: I guess is the segue from storyboard that is the problem .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used

```
   -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

       }
```

It is

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

       }
```

I hope you have typed it by mistake please share your result if it is something else than this

Comment: I have made the above changes but still its blank ?? I have no idea why ?

Comment: wat is blank ? have you set the delegate to your tableview just try adding NSLog inside your didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.the label in another controller which is supposed to set the text value of the value of the array selected in that row is blank.I have added log in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath its working fine I have the value but its not transfering to another controller.

Comment: **@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *DisplayMsg; @property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *DisplayMsgString;** in .h file  and  
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 
    
        
    self.DisplayMsg.text= self.DisplayMsgString;
 //   self.DisplayMsg.text= _DisplayMsgString;
    
} in .m file

Comment: I have posted the entire code for .m and .h .Let me know what I need to add ? Thanks again.

Comment: connected your UILabel in your xib to your File Owner

Comment: I just now created and made connections again .Still blank.Its not crashing just the value is not displayed on another controller.

Comment: tried printing the value in viewDidLoad just NSLog DisplayMsgString and set the label textcolor something different to your background color

Comment: Did that : Nslog Value is :  **str :  (null)**

Comment: I found the problem but still unable to resolve I have added :
    **cellvalue=[dataMsg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    NSLog(@"str :  %@",cellvalue);**  Nslog ---> this code is not executing I am not getting anything on the console ??

Comment: Basically cellvalue exists  but Nslog code is not executing ?

Comment: do you have values in your array i.e your DataMsg contains values?

Comment: Yes. 
    ViewControllerDisplayMsg *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"displayMsgSegueIdentifier"];
 is taking it Next view controller the rest of the code within didselectrow is not executing

Comment: Its directing jumping to viewdidload of the next controller

Comment: I guess -didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is not being called .I am checking for related answers.

Comment: why can't you try ViewControllerDisplayMsg *detail =[[ViewControllerDisplayMsg alloc]init];

Comment: I did that : I guess I have set segue from story board to uiviewcontroller of displayMsg for selection segue. (selection Segue and accessory action) are 2 types when i set for accessory action nothing happens its stuck at tableview

Comment: I will accept the above answer and reframe a new question.Thanks for the help,

Comment: Check the answer below can anything else be done to implement the same.Its working for now.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had segue from the story board The didselect method was not being called so -

```
(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // test segue.identifier if needed
    ViewControllerDisplayMsg *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    // set properties of viewController based on selection indexPath


    cellvalue=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"str :  %@",cellvalue);
    viewController.DisplayMsgtext = cellvalue;
```

}

This worked perfectly fine.I have to check it if this is right  way of implementing but otherwise its working fine now.

Comment: for your better understanding please look into this http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2

Comment: I have started coding tableview from that site itself but they do not have integrated code with json and custom cell and storyboard.Its not exactly what I was looking for.But Thank you for your support and motivation. Cheers.